# Unloading projects is very slow with MSVS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, ide

I'm working with MSVS 2012 on Win 7. I have a solution with ~270 projects. When I want to unload some, the process is **extremely** slow. So it is when I want to reload some. Does someone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Dominique

Comment: Personally, I would just create a solution for those one or two projects that I'm actively modifying, and use "make" for building the entire 270-project "system".  IMHO...

Comment: Not possible. Actually, the projects are supposed to load/unload very quickly. There must be something in my settings that prevent the process to work correctly. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Moving to SSD drives solved this problem for us.